# UIDragPreviewParameters visiblePath custom shape

Tags: ios, swift, drag-and-drop, uicollectionview, uibezierpath

I have a `UICollectionView` of custom shaped items.

I have iOS 11 drag and drop functionality implemented, and I need to create a `visiblePath` for my `UIDragPreviewParameters` to match the shape of the dragged item. I tried:

```
previewParameters.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
```

but it leaves a rectangular shaped shadow around the dragged item.

I need help with matching `visiblePath` to the dragged items shape, or to get rid off the rectangular shadow.

Comment: after dragging try to set the 
layer.borderColor = UIColor.clear.CGcolor
for the view in question

Comment: Didn't help. although setting borderRadius to some number make it look better than the rectangle.

Comment: I have the same problem as you. Have you found a solution to remove the shadow?

Answer (score 0):

Actually, it is simple ... do not implement this function

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, 
dragPreviewParametersForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> 
UIDragPreviewParameters?
```

and the dragged object shape will be exactly the same as the item you dragged from the collection view.